# Terraform - Error: Provider configuration not present (passing multiple Azure providers)

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I am following this guide https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/v0.13/website/docs/configuration/modules.html.md#passing-providers-explicitly

This is a brand new Terraform project ie no resources and an empty state file! The version of terraform is Terraform v0.14.5.

In the calling module I have my providers set up as follows

```
terraform {

  backend "azurerm" {

  }
   required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.68.0"
    }
  }
}


provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "lz"
  subscription_id = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"

  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "prd"
  subscription_id = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"

  features {}
}
```

And I am calling modules passing multiple providers like this

```
module "prod" {
  source = "../../../Terraform/modules/LandingZone"

  providers = {
    azurerm.lz = azurerm.lz
    azurerm.prd = azurerm.prd
  }
}
```

In the called module I have this in the providers.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.68.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {

  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
   alias           = "lz"
   features{}
}


provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "prd"
  features{}
}
```

Up to this point init and plan works fine. However when I try to create resources like this

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
  provider= azurerm.lz
  
  for_each = var.rg_names  
  name     = each.value
  location = "Australia Southeast"
}
```

I get this error message

```
Error: Provider configuration not present

To work with module.trn.module.rg.azurerm_resource_group.this its original
provider configuration at
module.trn.module.rg.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"].lz is
required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider configuration
is removed while objects created by that provider still exist in the state.
Re-add the provider configuration to destroy
module.trn.module.rg.azurerm_resource_group.this, after which you can remove
the provider configuration again.
```

Comment: There are a few different related issues here, but the root cause is that you changed the provider configuration for a resource in the managed config to something that cannot be updated by the provider while it still exists in the state. You need to recreate (Delete and Create) this resource for the new provider configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/configuration.html#alias-multiple-provider-configurations) guide you should declare `configuration_aliases` inside terraform block for required providers. You can try this also.

Comment: Yes Tried that also but its a v15 feature of Terraform

Answer (score 0):

From the guide you have linked,

> A proxy configuration block is one that contains only the `alias` argument.

Your provider blocks in your module have more than just the `alias` argument, so they are probably not being set up as proxy provider configurations. Try removing the `features{}` part from the provider blocks inside your module.